# Prevent sync data in postman

Tags: http, postman

Postman software is tools that use for execute HTTP request with methods (put,get and ...)

This software is free and you can save all request in cloud

The synchronize data is auto with Postman but it take about 5 second for sync

Can i stop it or use it offline only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see [Sync Documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/syncing) And also [Sync Regarding Post](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/203492852-How-do-I-disable-Sync-).

Sync button is here:

[image]

Comment: I saw it but in software i dont find "Disable sync" menu,Do you see it?

Comment: Do you can help me?

Comment: Look carefully in the postman app, you will find what I just showed you :)

Comment: Because i sign in postman,Postman send all request to cloud,i signout now and it is working good now Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can't turn off sync, you have to sign out of postman to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** – Store your sensitive data within the Current Values field in the environment template so that it isn’t synced.

[image: environment variables]

---

Turning sync off isn’t possible but they added the notion of Sessions in a previous release that enables you to store sensitive information (API keys, tokens, etc) as environment variables that aren’t synced.

Sessions FAQ – https://blog.getpostman.com/2018/08/09/sessions-faq/

The RFC – [Sessions in Postman 8](https://community.postman.com/t/sessions-in-postman/1925)

Data in Current Value is not synced to Postman’s servers. It is a common security practice to store passwords/keys/tokens in Current Value, and use the Initial Value column as a placeholder.